# Access Ubuntu desktop remotely from Mac OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, osx, vnc, remote-desktop

I would like to be able to access my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop (not just terminal) from Mac OS (Mojave), and have tried a couple solutions, with less-then-desirable results:

- Installing google chrome remote desktop caused terminal to not launch properly.
- XRDP would only display a blank screen on the remote desktop client.
- Am considering trying x11vnc but I'm not sure how well-supported any of the macos x11vnc clients are

Does anyone have any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Comment: VNC is the way to go. Try TigerVNC.

Comment: MacOS built-in screen sharing feature uses the VNC protocol, you don't need a third-party client any more. But I've been using JollysFastVNC for many years, it works well.